# Why does jQuery 2.0.2 add empty style attribute to body

Tags: jquery, styles

The new jQuery 2.0.2 adds "style" attribute to the body tag in DOM tree. Is there any specific reason?

Printscreen:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While this doesn't actually affect anything it's still a valid question.

The reason is this code:

```
// Workaround failing boxSizing test due to offsetWidth returning wrong value
// with some non-1 values of body zoom, ticket #13543
jQuery.swap( body, body.style.zoom != null ? { zoom: 1 } : {}, function() {
    support.boxSizing = div.offsetWidth === 4;
});
```

This is just a test for [boxSizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) support. `jQuery.swap()` is described in the source as:

> A method for quickly swapping in/out CSS properties to get correct calculations.

`body.style.zoom != null ? { zoom: 1 } : {}` returns `zoom: 1` if `body.style.zoom` is **not** `null` and an empty object if it is. The returned value is then applied to the `body` element which is why it has an empty `style` tag.

Comment: Actually it does for display:table type body